# MatLab list files (excluding directories) in a folder

Tags: matlab, path

So I know I can list all the files and directories in my current folder using functions like `dir()` or `ls()`, and I know once listed, I can tell them from each other with the field `isdir`.

But is there a way to exclude the directories from the very beggining and list the files alone?

Even better, is there a way to exclude the current `.` and parent `..` directories -that will (of course) show everytime- and list every other file and directory? Seriously, who uses `ls()` wondering if `.` is there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `dir` is whatever the operating system is feeding it. So it might be different depending on what system you're running. Here is my approach to that:

```
list=dir();
CleanList=setdiff({list.name},{'.','..'})';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a built in method for this, but why not write a custom function to do what you want?

Such as:

```
function list = files_dir(varargin)
% Similar functionality to 'dir', but only returns files (no folders)

list = dir(varargin{:});

list([list.isdir]) = [];
```

You can then customise this to perform other functionality, such as excluding hidden files.

And for your second request, where directories `'.'` and `'..'` are excluded:

```
function list = dir_exclude_self(varargin)
% same as 'dir', but doesn't return '.' or '..'

list = dir(varargin{:});

self_indices = ismember({list.name}, {'.', '..'});
list(self_indices) = [];
```

If you put functions like this in a specific place on your computer you can ensure they are always available to use by adding them to the MATLAB path in your `startup.m` file.

Comment: Good idea, I will. I just find it odd that there's no built ins for what I regard as a common problem...

Comment: Yes, I usually find it's the other way around – I spend ages writing code which is already a built-in!

Comment: And then proudly call myself "McMa, inventor of the wheel" :D